# Repairable system and the sum of GEV random variables

Tags: mathematical-statistics, survival, reliability, extreme-value

We know that $X\sim {\mathrm  {GEV}}(\alpha ,\beta ,0)$ and $Y\sim {\mathrm  {GEV}}(\alpha ,\beta ,0)$ then $X+Y\sim {\mathrm  {Logistic}}(2\alpha ,\beta )$.

I am wondering, what will be $X+Y+Z$ like, if $Z\sim {\mathrm  {GEV}}(\alpha ,\beta ,0)$ also. And more generally what will $\sum X_{i}$ be if $X_{i}\sim {\mathrm  {GEV}}(\alpha ,\beta ,0)$.

A practical example would be a device whose lifespan follows $X\sim {\mathrm  {GEV}}(\alpha ,\beta ,0)$. But the device can be repaired, instantaneously once failed, for $i$ times.